# Migration error(django.db.utils.OperationalError)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, deployment

I'm trying to migrate my custom user model and I run makemigrations command to make migrations for new models. But when I run migrate command it throws this error :

> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory,
> **kwasync) django.db.utils.OperationalError

**Trace back:**

```
    (venv_ruling) C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\ruling>python manage.py migrate
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
        self.connect()
      File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
        self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
      File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
        connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
      File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    psycopg2.OperationalError
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\ruling\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\ruling\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1290, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1680, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\features.py", line 93, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 329, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "C:\Users\enosh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 603, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\enosh\venv_ruling\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """extend usermodel"""

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'CustomUser'
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'rulings',
        'USER': 'xxxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxx',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

The postgresql's database is empty.(ver.12.6)

I just mentioned user model and settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have left the port empty for the question or it is actually empty, but try this in the console and see if the connection is successful.

```
conn=psycopg2.connect(database="rulings", user="xxx", password="xxx",port=5432)
```

Also this might not be your port(it is the default but yours might be changed) check your port number  `\conninfo` in the postgres shell. And let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the host_ip or the port number in the settings.py file of django.